# How to run node and django server at a time

Tags: python, node.js, django, web-development-server

I am making a video chatting application in which I will use web sockets from npm and I have written WebSocket related code in a server.js file like this

```
var webSocketServ = require('ws').Server;


var wss = new webSocketServ({
    port: 8000
})

var users = {};
var otherUser;
wss.on('connection', function (conn) {
    console.log("User connected");

    conn.on('message', function (message) {
        var data;
        .
        .
        .
     and so on
```

and for managing URLs I used Django,
so my problem is when I use python manage.py runserver, server.js is not running and application is not connecting to the server and if I run "node server.js" application is connecting to server but I am unable to manage URL as in Django code

so I opened two instances of terminals and ran node in one terminal and python in another but I know its not the correct way and it won't be efficient while hosting

is there any way to run both servers at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the two servers to appear to run on the same port, you'll need to set up one to proxy certain requests to the other. (I'd recommend having the Node.js server proxy everything non-websocket to Django using e.g. https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy).

If you don't need the two servers to run on the same port, just change them to use different ports, in which case you'll access the two contents on different URLs. You can change that `port: 8000` in the Node app, or in Django's `runserver`, do e.g. `runserver 127.0.0.1:8010` (or `0.0.0.0:8010` to expose the dev server beyond your own machine).

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestions. I don't need same port for both servers , so I am using 2 different ports in 2 different terminals, but at the time of hosting can I use 2 different servers ?

Comment: Yes, depending on the hosting you're using.